# Composer Install Dependency into Subdirectory

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

Been banging my head against this one, and would hugely appreciate some advice, please.

I own two packages, and would like the dependency to install into a subdirectory of the ***main package***, rather than into the ***vendor*** directory.

A subsequent requirement is to only update the dependency.

Here are some images to describe what I mean.

**This is how it installs at the moment.**

[image]

**This is how I am trying to get it to install.**

[image]

So far, I've read a few answers, and thought that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45000004/1219112) might be the solution, but it isn't quite what I want either.

**Effectively, I've tried this as 'main' composer file.**

*composer.json*

```
{
  "name" : "Test",
  "require": {
    "me/main-repo": "dev-master"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**And this within *that* package**

*composer.json*

```
{
   "name" : "me/main-repo",
   "require": {
      "me/dependancy-repo": "dev-master"
   },
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**And when that didn't work, I updated the latter to this (the directory I want it to install into is named *Core*.**

*composer.json*

```
{
   "name" : "me/main-repo",
   "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../../packages/Core"
      }
   ],
   require: {
       "me/dependency-repo" : "dev-master"
   }
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**And in the Core directory ...**

*composer.json*

```
{
   "name" : "me/main-repo", // this seems quite wrong, looking at it now
   "require": {
       "me/dependancy-repo": "dev-master"
   }
}
```

Which gave the same results ..
In fact, the second shot at it doesn't actually make sense reading it back, but I've now had so many composer.json files it's gotten a little messy!

Comment: Why do you need it installed in this kind of hierarchy? what about people who use your "dependency" in their own projects without your main package?

Comment: @Scuzzy It's a framework. The dependency is part of the framework. The 'main' part would be their controllers etc, the dependency would be part they shouldn't touch, but would be updated. 
For them to try use the dependency elsewhere wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but I'll be happy to be proven wrong. AFAIK, Composer puts all dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies ad infinitum) into the same folder, primarily to avoid duplicates when multiple project dependencies share the same child dependency but also to simplify the autoloader.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I've come to believe that might be the case, but was hoping not.

Comment: Honestly, this does not make any sense to me. Even if you will able to achieve this structure, it will get you nothing more than a trouble. If you're writing a dependency it should not be your concern where Composer will place files. Same as end user. What should mater is namespaces structure, because that's what people will use. Nobody will include files manually, it is Composer's job. So treat packages placement as Composer internal behavior and implementation detail and try to not rely on it by creating some nested dependencies tree.

Comment: It would be great if people could stop the "this doesn't make sense to me" comments as they aren't helpful. 1. You don't know the project I'm working on and 2. I've responded to that already. It's just noise.